# GDAL in docker using pipelines in gitlab

Tags: python, gdal, docker

I want use gitlab to test python with GDAL library

`pip install gdal`

is not working

I use gitlab to CI/CD

Source code of project:

https://github.com/lazyspot/georeference-image-library

It is possible to use docker or I must use virtual machine with installed GDAL?

Comment: If you want to use GitLab CI/CD your repo needs to be hosted in GitLab, not GitHub. GitLab has an [import feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/github.html) that makes this easy.

Comment: Project hosted on Github but CI/CD is running on Gitlab

Comment: Ah, I see, the project is being mirrored across the two services.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have GDAL installed. Use [before_script](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script-and-after_script) call to install GDAL:

```
default:
  before_script:
    - apt update && apt install libgdal-dev
```